# UITextView not displaying keyboard when using its delegate to detect when textview is begun to be edited

Tags: ios, uitextview, first-responder

I'm trying to work with a textview but its having odd reactions. The textview is where the user enters their information that will be sent to me. Basically I've designed my interface in interface builder and got it looking correct. I have entered place holder text: "Enter your issue here". When I run the app the textview works correctly, I can delete the pre entered text and compose a message. However I need to place a ui tool bar above the key board so I can give the user a way of canceling input. i've implemented its delegate, `UITextViewDelegate` and implemented

`- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{}`

which does get fired when I tap the text view. However the textview now does not give me the keyboard! it just sits there awaiting input but never displays the keyboard. I need to use `textViewShouldBeginEditing` so I can tell when the user touches the text view to activate the text entry and attach the uitoolbar I. If I remove the `textViewShouldBeginEditing` the text view goes back to responding being tapped. I've tried a good few thing, ensured the right connections are made in interface builder, set the delegates etc, etc but nothing seams to fix this.

Any suggestions are welcome and if any more information is needed let me know.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you returning TRUE in the delegate?

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
       //Do your things
       return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: No, XCode doesn't generate error/warnings when you forget the return in a method

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(myMethod)
 name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
 object:myTextField];
```

you can use `UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification` or `UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification`